# Control over clipping of the tableview footer/section

Tags: uitableview, footer

I have defined a footer section view for a tableview that i would like to be wider than my tableview. While i set the `clipToBounds` property to `NO` for my tableview my footer section is still being clipped. Is there a way to disable the clipping of the header/footer section for a tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best approach for this is to have a custom background for your cells that would make them look narrower than the actual table view width.